# Error when leaving input blank in ASP

Tags: asp-classic, active-directory

I am developing a script to allow users to write to Active Directory. The problem is that, when I leave a field blank, it results in an error. When, however, I put a value in, even a space, it seems happy. I have the following code:

```
 <%@LANGUAGE="VBScript">
%>
<%
if isEmpty(request.form("subval")) then

response.write("You did not submit the form, please <a href='ldap.asp'>go back</a>")

else
'If the subval field is empty, we know the form has been submitted OK
dim firstname, lastname, email, telephonenumber, mobile, description
ADUser = "LDAP://OU=Staff,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=internal"
' Make AD connection and run query

subval = request.querystring("account_name")
'This value held the CN earlier, it is now overwriten here

Set objCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objCon.provider ="ADsDSOObject"
objCon.Properties("User ID") = "EXAMPLE\Exampe"
objCon.Properties("Password") = "TestPassword"
objCon.Properties("Encrypt Password") = TRUE
objCon.open "Active Directory Provider"

Set objCom = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set objCom.ActiveConnection = objCon
objCom.CommandText ="select sAMAccountName, distinguishedName FROM '"+ ADUser +"' where sAMAccountname='"& subval &"'"
Set objRS = objCom.Execute
distinguishedName = objRS.Fields("distinguishedName")    
objRS.Close
objCon.Close
Set objRS = Nothing
Set objCom = Nothing
'We select the distinguishedName from AD

firstname = request.form("firstname")
lastname = request.form("lastname")
email = request.form("email")
telephonenumber = request.form("telephonenumber")
mobile = request.form("mobile")
description = request.form("description")
Const ADS_PROPERTY_UPDATE = 2 

Set objUser = GetObject _  ("LDAP://" & distinguishedName) 
if (IsNull(firstname)) Then
    firstname = "  "
end if

if (IsNull(lastname)) Then
    lastname = "  "
end if

if (IsNull(email)) Then
    email = "  "
end if

if (IsNull(telephonenumber)) Then
    telephonenumber = "  "
end if

if (IsNull(mobile)) Then
    mobile = "  "
end if

if (IsNull(description)) Then
    description = "  "
end if

   objUser.Put "givenName", firstname
   objUser.Put "mail", email
   objUser.Put "sn", lastname
   objUser.Put "mobile", mobile
   objUser.Put "description", description
   objUser.Put "telephoneNumber", telephonenumber
   objUser.SetInfo
   Response.Write("User data for "& subval &" has been modified")
   end if
%>
```

The error I get whenever I leave a field blank is why I am trying to inject spaces into the variables since that seems to work in my form.

The error I get is on the SetInfo line

> error '8007200b' 
>   /updateldap.asp, line 68

I'm not sure what I can try since I've done all the stuff I can think of

Comment: Not related to your question. You have
 <%@LANGUAGE="VBScript">
%>

should be  <%@LANGUAGE="VBScript"%>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

8007200b = LDAP_INVALID_SYNTAX (The attribute syntax specified to the directory service is invalid)

I would say that you have worked out what the issue is.  **LDAP attributes cannot be NULL**.  You probably don't even need to have spaces, an empty string might work as well.

e.g.

```
if (IsNull(firstname)) Then
    firstname = ""
end if
```